# Shared Calendars not available in Outlook 2011

Tags: ms-office, calendar, sharing

Shared Calendars is not available in my Navigation Pane.

I am trying to add colleagues calendars. I understand they should show up in a Shared Calendars Section in the Navigation Pane. But I don't have that section at all. Have I hidden that somehow? Is there a way to add it back?

[image]

I use this process to add the shared calendar: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/912265

1. On the File menu, point to Open, and then click Other User's Folder.
2. Click Find User
3. Type the name of the person who granted you access,
   click Find, click the person's name, and then click OK.
4. On the Type menu, click Calendar, and then click OK.
5. The shared calendar appears in the navigation pane under the Shared heading.

I know that the calendar is shared properly because other colleagues with same version of Mac & Outlook are able to view it.

Software:
 - Outlook 2011 version 14.5.1
 - OS-X 10.9.5 Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

I have searched on the web for days on how to resolve this issue but no solution.

Here is how I solved mine;

Delete your Outlook profile as the calendar is corrupt on it

Link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-profiles-in-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c

Then, close and reopen outlook, you will be prompted to create a new profile.

Go back to your calendar on outlook. Add a calendar now and it should show up on the left view.

It worked for me and it should work for you.